# RichText widget in custom multifield widget no listener is getting invoked on edit

Tags: extjs, aem

I am trying to create a component in AEM CQ5 which will generate a quiz module. My requirement is to create a dialog which will allow me to create multiple questions each with multiple answers. My dialog xml is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <categories 
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Questions & Answers">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <questions-answers
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        title="Questions & Answers"
                        name="./qasegment"
                        xtype="dialogfieldset">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <link
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Click on Add item to add questions. Once question is added, click on Edit Answers to add answers and the destination URLs"
                                    name="./questionsAnswers"
                                    typeHint="String"
                                    xtype="multifield">                         
                                    <fieldConfig 
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        xtype="widgets.configurableQandAfield"/>
                                </link>
                            </items>
                    </questions-answers>
                </items>       
            </categories>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

From and xtype:mutlifield, I am referring to a custom extjs widget which is as follows. This will create the (question + question configurations + Add answer multifield ) multifield.

```
NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

     /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.HiddenField
     */
    hiddenField: null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    questionField: null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    linkField: null,

    textField:null,

    answerOptions:null,

    answerType:null,

    widgetConfig: null,


    constructor: function(config) {
        config = config || { };
        var defaults = {
            "border": true,
            "layout": "form",
            "labelSeparator": ":",
            "padding": "10px"
        };
        this.widgetConfig = config;
        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        EeWeb.ConfigurableQandAField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    // overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
    initComponent: function() {
        EeWeb.ConfigurableQandAField.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        // Add a hidden field to hold our result to store.
        this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
            name: this.name
        });
        this.add(this.hiddenField);


   //if the destination type is text response
    this.questionField= new CQ.form.RichText({
        fieldLabel:'destination Text',
        name:'./questionField',  
        allowBlank: true,
        enableSourceEdit: true,
        hidden:true,
        externalStyleSheets:"[/etc/designs/web-2013/clientlibs_all.css]",
        emptyText: "Enter the text to show to the customer on answer selection",
        width: 500,
        rtePlugins :{
            spellcheck:{features:"*"},
            image:{features:"*"},
            edit:{features:"*"},
            justify:{features:"*"},
            misctools:{features:"*"},
            table:{features:"*"},
            undo:{features:"*"}
        },
        listeners : {
            change :{
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            },
            destroy: {
                scope:this,
                fn:this.destroyRichText
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.questionField);

        var fieldsetConfig = CQ.Ext.apply({}, {
           xtype: 'fieldset',
           title: 'Edit Answer',
           // title or checkboxToggle creates fieldset header
           columnWidth: 0.5,
           checkboxToggle: true,
           collapsed: true,
           items :[
               {    
                xtype: "fieldset",
                title: 'Answer configurations',
                autoHeight:true,
                items: [
                        new CQ.Ext.form.RadioGroup({
                                vertical: false,
                                id:"answerType",
                                items: [
                                    {boxLabel: 'Text Answer', name: 'answerType', inputValue: 1, checked:true},
                                    {boxLabel: 'Image Answer', name: 'answerType', inputValue: 2}
                                ]    

                        }),
                        new CQ.Ext.form.RadioGroup({
                                vertical: false,
                                id:"answerOptions",
                                items: [
                                    {boxLabel: 'Single Answer', name: 'answerOptions', inputValue: 1, checked:true},
                                    {boxLabel: 'Multiple Answer', name: 'answerOptions', inputValue: 2}
                                ]    

                        }),
                       ]
                },
                {
                xtype: "multifield",
                    fieldConfig : {
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: "widgets.configurablemultiAnswerfield",
                                hideLabel: true,
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
           ]
        });
        this.textField = new CQ.Ext.form.FieldSet(fieldsetConfig);
        this.add(this.textField);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processInit
    processInit: function (path, record) { 
        this.linkTextField.processInit(path, record);
        this.linkField.processInit(path, record);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue: function(value) {
        var link = JSON.parse(value);
        this.linkTextField.setValue(link.text);
        this.linkField.show();
        this.hiddenField.setValue(value);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue: function() {
        return this.getRawValue();
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
    getRawValue: function() {
        return JSON.stringify("test");
    },

    // private
    updateHidden: function() {
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    },

    editAnswer: function(value) {
                alert("radio group change");
     },

destroyRichText : function(){
    this.el.dom={};
}

});

// Register our new xtype.
CQ.Ext.reg('widgets.configurableQandAfield', NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField);
```

It works very smooth when I create the dialog. But when I edit the component and the dialog opens, any edit is not getting updated. This is because no listener is invoked to update the hidden value. I have tried all listeners - change,blur,destroy,sync and push. But none of the listener is getting invoked.

Please help me out. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

try overriding parent method processValue in your multifield JS and invoke updateHidden method init

Example:

```
    // private
    updateHidden: function() {
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    },
    processValue: function(value) {        
        if ((value === undefined) || (value === null)) {
            value = "";
        }    
        // calling updateHidden() as change event not functioning for RTE widget
        this.updateHidden();
        return value;                  
    },
```